# Need help using prototypeJS

Tags: javascript, forms, events, click, prototype

I have some issue with prototypeJS today which I am using for a new project so here's my code :

```
var div = $('addcontact');
Event.observe(div, 'click', respondToClick);
function respondToClick(event) {    
    var form = $('contactForm');
    form.setStyle(
          {display : initial}
    );
}
```

I don't understand why it  is not working, $('contactForm') has a display : none as a css property, so what I want to do is display it when clicking on $('addcontact').

Comment: It should be `{ display: "initial" }` - the value of the property should be a string.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I corrected what you suggested but it's still not working..

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure what `"initial"` is supposed to do; if you want the form to be visible, the value should be `"block"` or maybe `"inline-block"`.

Comment: `"initial"` is the default value of `display`.

Comment: I tried with `'inline-block'` and `'block'` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well make sure you check your console for errors. You didn't post your markup, but [here is a jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/p8pmo5m3/) showing that your code (with `"initial"` as a string) should work.

Comment: Hi thank you again for your answer, your example was right indeed, It wasn't working because I've put the `'none'` attribute directly in the `<div>` using `style="display : none"`( it was only for a test). But it seems that doing it this way blocks `display` when we try to modify it with a script.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype has two `Element` methods that control CSS `display` property: `show()` and `hide()`, provided that the initial value is set **inline** (as is the case).

So, your snippet can be optimized as follows:

```
Event.observe($('addcontact'), 'click', function()
{ 
    $('contactForm').show();
});
```

In addition, `show()` automatically sets the appropriate `display` property to the element involved: `block`, `ìnline`, `table`, `table-row` and so on. And `hide()` sets `display` to `none`.

If you want `show()` or `hide()` several elements at once, then use the form:

```
$('element_1','element_2', ..., 'element_n').invoke('show');
$('element_1','element_2', ..., 'element_n').invoke('hide');
```

### EDIT

If you want to switch on/off the `display` property of a element depending on an event, then:

```
Event.observe($('element'),'click', function()
{
    $('otherElement').toggle();
}
```